# Excel - Off Page Reference to Microsoft Query

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, ms-query

I am utilizing Microsoft Query in Excel to tap into an ERP table structure like Crystal would do.

In writing the SQL, is there a way to have a filter pulled from the active Excel worksheet that is embedded in the SQL instead of prompting and editing the query?

My main problem is a `Like [Prompt]%` in the Excel GUI for the users to change like order numbers.

Is it possible to do an off page reference from MS Query to Excel?

Answer (score 0):

If by "Microsoft Query", you're talking about the window that looks like it was coded for Windows 95, stop using it. This is provided for retro-compatibility.

Anyway, if you've displayed the criteria bar in MS query, you can type a name between brackets e.g. `[Something]` and MS query will prompt you to fill a value.

Not what you want yet but getting close. When you return to Excel and refresh the query, the prompt will now offer you the possibility to use a cell instead of a value you need to type every type.

In the more modern connection utility accessible via menu data > Connections (+ available even if you created your table via MS Query btw), you can achieve that by using question marks in the `WHERE` clause.

For instance, instead of `SomeField = 'SomeValue'`, write `SomeField = ?`
Then, click on the Parameters button and you'll see all the parameters you've set, each of them can be attached to a cell's value.

Comment: Noted on the question mark. Any chance you have a recommendation for a platform that should be used? And is ?% valid - learning as I go.

Comment: Oops! I understood neither of your questions ... what do you mean by platform? and ?% would be used to do what?

Comment: That is OK. You pointed me in the right direction. I will edit the where clause of the connection.